# Throwable argument 'ex' to 'System.out.println()' call

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, throwable

I am currently working on a stock management system. In the system there is option to register as seen below:

[image: Registration page]

The following code shows the register button method:

```js
        btnRegister.setOnAction(e ->{// register button method
            try {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane root =         loader.load(getClass().getResource("Register.fxml").openStream());
            RegisterController Msg = loader.getController();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().setAll(
                getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm()
            );
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            ((Node) e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        });
```

I am getting the following warning:

```
Warning:(64, 36) Throwable argument 'ex' to 'System.out.println()' call
```

Could someone explain this warning and possible way to resolve this?

Will this have any impact later on with new changes if ignored?

It is complaining about the following line of the code from the register method specifically, where the exception is:

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: Printing `System.out.println(ex);`  prints out `ex.toString()` which maybe unhelpful. For printout simply use `ex.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Without the stack trace it can be very difficult to determine _where_ the problem occurred. And if there's nested exceptions you're likely even hiding _what_ the actual problem is. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) to understand why stack traces are helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be calling `ex.printStackTrace()` instead.

Using `System.out.println(ex)` hides a lot of useful, possibly even pivotal, information. For example, if you run the following:

```java
package com.example;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      throwException();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
    }
  }

  public static void throwException() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("something went wrong");
  }
}
```

You get the following output:

```
java.lang.Exception: something went wrong
```

That only tells you the type of exception and the error message. For trivial applications that may be enough to know what and where the problem is. But consider a complex application with thousands of lines of code; this kind of exception reporting tells you *nothing* about where the problem occurred.

Now replace `System.out.println(ex)` with `ex.printStackTrace()` and you'll see the new output:

```
java.lang.Exception: something went wrong
    at com.example.Main.throwException(Main.java:14)
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

This is the stack trace. From a stack trace you can see the flow of execution and also see what specific line of code threw the exception. Note though that you can configure compilation to discard debugging information which means you'll stop getting source file names and line numbers, but you'll still be provided with class and method names (better than nothing).

It goes further than this. Exceptions in Java can have a *cause* as well as multiple *suppressed exceptions*. This is described in greater detail by the [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html) documentation. Here's an (contrived) example:

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      throwException();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void throwException() throws Exception {
    IOException ioe = new IOException("could not write to stream");
    // typically suppressed exceptions come from a try-with-resources statement
    ioe.addSuppressed(new IOException("unable to close stream"));

    throw new Exception("something went wrong", ioe);
  }
}
```

This gives the following output:

```java
java.lang.Exception: something went wrong
    at com.example.Main.throwException(Main.java:19)
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: could not write to stream
    at com.example.Main.throwException(Main.java:16)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to close stream
        at com.example.Main.throwException(Main.java:17)
        ... 1 more
```

If `System.out.println(ex)` was used instead then you wouldn't get either the `Caused by:` or `Suppressed:` sections. This means you have no idea what the actual problem is, nor if there are hidden problems, which, as you can probably imagine, makes it much more difficult to fix.

There is another difference between `System.out.println(ex)` and `ex.printStackTrace()`. The former prints to the *standard output* stream (i.e. `System.out`) whereas the latter prints to the *standard error* stream (i.e. `System.err`). As an exception is an error it makes sense to print it to the error stream, but you can change the target via `Throwable#printStackTrace(PrintStream)` or `Throwable#printStackTrace(PrintWriter)`. For instance, `ex.printStackTrace(System.out)` would print the stack trace to standarad output.

And finally, for "real" applications you'll probably want to use a logging framework. These frameworks can output even more information, such as the thread the exception was reported by and the timestamp of *when* the exception occurred.

---

Check out the [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) Q&A to better understand stack traces and why they're useful.

Answer (score 7):

For printing the exception details, Exception class already have a method name "printStackTrace()",

```
 System.out.println(ex); //not recommended
```

Use this

```
ex.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation why `System.out.println(ex);` is not recommended

Comment: That prints the stacktrace to `System.err` instead of `System.out`. Since the original code was writing output to `System.out`, `ex.printStackTrace(System.out)` would be closer to the original code. (However logically the output does belong to the error stream.)

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
  return "";
} catch (IllegalStateException illegalStateException) {
        System.out.println(illegalStateException.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    }
```

When used without the String type System.out.println(exception); // 'Throwable' argument 'exception' to 'System.out.println()' call

PT_BR Brasil