# JavaFX multiple threads: array vs observableList

Tags: java, javafx

Based on another stack overflow topic ([JavaFX MapProperty behave like an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266723/javafx-mapproperty-behave-like-an-array)) kind people help me making a solution where I could add observability to an existing approach where I was using an array. I'm budling a small app where I am controlling a "moving head" with pan & tilt movement and are using executorServices (scheduleAtFixedRate) to send new values to my hardware (the movinghead). The problem is that I see some performance-issue (I think) when using the observablelist. I see no performance-issue when using the array.

Below is an example that can reproduce the issue and under the code is described what to do to generate the issue.

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class App extends Application {

    RadioButton radioButtonUseArray;
    RadioButton radioButtonUseObservableList;
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService1;
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService2;
    int speed = 10;

    private final byte[] dmxDataArray = new byte[512];
    dmxDataObservable dmxDataArrayObservable = new dmxDataObservable(dmxDataArray);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        dmxDataArrayObservable.getBytes().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {

                System.out.println("Data updated");

            }

        });

        Button buttonStart = new Button("Start");
        buttonStart.setPrefWidth(100);
        buttonStart.setOnAction(event -> {

            StartGenerator1();
            StartGenerator2();

        });

        Button buttonStop = new Button("Stop");
        buttonStop.setPrefWidth(100);
        buttonStop.setOnAction(event -> {

            StopGenerator1();
            StopGenerator2();

        });

        HBox hBoxWithStartStop1 = new HBox();
        hBoxWithStartStop1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBoxWithStartStop1.setSpacing(10);
        HBox.setHgrow(hBoxWithStartStop1, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hBoxWithStartStop1.getChildren().addAll(buttonStart, buttonStop);

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        radioButtonUseArray = new RadioButton("Use Array");
        radioButtonUseArray.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        radioButtonUseArray.setSelected(true);

        radioButtonUseObservableList = new RadioButton("Use Observablelist");
        radioButtonUseObservableList.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        HBox hBoxWithRadioButtons = new HBox();
        hBoxWithRadioButtons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBoxWithRadioButtons.setSpacing(10);
        HBox.setHgrow(hBoxWithRadioButtons, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hBoxWithRadioButtons.getChildren().addAll(radioButtonUseArray, radioButtonUseObservableList);

        VBox vBoxWithAllOptions = new VBox();
        vBoxWithAllOptions.setSpacing(10);
        vBoxWithAllOptions.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBoxWithAllOptions.getChildren().addAll(hBoxWithStartStop1, hBoxWithRadioButtons);

        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(vBoxWithAllOptions), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {

            StopGenerator1();
            StopGenerator2();

        });

        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public void StartGenerator1() {

        if (this.executorService1 != null) {

            this.executorService1.shutdown();

        }

        try {

            this.executorService1 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            this.executorService1.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::SendDataToDataContainers1, 0L, speed, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);

        } catch (Exception r) {

           r.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public void StopGenerator1() {

        if (this.executorService1 != null) {

            this.executorService1.shutdown();

        }

    }

    public void StartGenerator2() {

        if (this.executorService2 != null) {

            this.executorService2.shutdown();

        }

        try {

            this.executorService2 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            this.executorService2.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::SendDataToDataContainers2, 0L, speed, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);

        } catch (Exception r) {

            r.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public void StopGenerator2() {

        if (this.executorService2 != null) {

            this.executorService2.shutdown();

        }

    }

    public void SendDataToDataContainers1() {

        if (radioButtonUseArray.isSelected()) {

            dmxDataArray[1] = (byte) 1;
            dmxDataArray[2] = (byte) 1;
            dmxDataArray[3] = (byte) 1;
            dmxDataArray[4] = (byte) 1;
            System.out.println("Running using array");

        } else if (radioButtonUseObservableList.isSelected()) {

            try {

                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(1, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(2, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(3, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(4, (byte) 1);
                System.out.println("Running using Observablelist");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

    public void SendDataToDataContainers2() {

        if (radioButtonUseArray.isSelected()) {

            try {

                dmxDataArray[1] = (byte) 1;
                dmxDataArray[2] = (byte) 1;
                dmxDataArray[3] = (byte) 1;
                dmxDataArray[4] = (byte) 1;
                System.out.println("Running using array ");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        } else if (radioButtonUseObservableList.isSelected()) {

            try {

                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(1, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(2, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(3, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(4, (byte) 1);

                System.out.println("Running using Observablelist");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is the dmxDataObservable class:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class dmxDataObservable {

    private final ObservableList<Byte> bytes;

    public dmxDataObservable(byte[] bytes) {

        this.bytes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (byte b : bytes) {

            this.bytes.add(b);

        }

    }

    public void setByte(int index, byte b) {

        bytes.set(index, b);

    }

    public Byte getByte(int index) {
        return bytes.get(index);
    }

    public ObservableList<Byte> getBytes() {
        // prevent things like getBytes().add() etc.
        return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(bytes);
    }

    public byte[] getBytesAsArray() {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[bytes.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
            byteArray[i] = bytes.get(i);
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

If I run the App and click "Start" the app will run and add data to the array. If I select "Use Observablelist" I will see below errors at some point:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1091)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.nextRemove(ListChangeBuilder.java:204)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.nextSet(ListChangeBuilder.java:453)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.nextSet(ObservableListBase.java:115)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.set(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:162)
    at org.example/org.example.dmxDataObservable.setByte(dmxDataObservable.java:24)
    at org.example/org.example.App.SendDataToDataContainers1(App.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

If I keep the app running and select "Use array" then the app is again working without errors.

I know the call to the array and observablelist is very intensively but that is what I need to do in my App.

Comment: There are quite a few concurrency issues in this code. I would guess that is where your errors are coming from (the `UnsupportedOperationException` _might_ be from something else). Also, your exception reporting is not ideal. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61928171/6395627) and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627), then [edit] your question to add the stack traces.

Comment: Those concurrency issues include: (1) Using the `counter` field from multiple threads; (2) Accessing UI objects from a thread other than the _JavaFX Application Thread_; (3) If you run both generators simultaneously, you have two threads interacting with the `ObservableList`, which is not a thread-safe implementation in this case.

Comment: Example updated with printStackTrace() and counter removed. Errors replaces with the stacktrace.

Comment: These are not performance issues, but threading issues. As stated in a previous comment, `ObservableList` is not designed to be used by multiple threads simultaneously. You can fix the problem in the example by replacing the threading code with JavaFX Animation code (e.g. a `Timeline`: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685975/2189127)). Whether or not that will work in your real application we cannot know.

Comment: I have updated the topic title and posted an answer (if this is not the right ting to do then please let me know).

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do overall here. Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266723/javafx-mapproperty-behave-like-an-array) said you wanted to have an array-like structure that was observable, so it could be used in the UI. But here you are not using the data in the UI, you are pushing it out to some hardware. It's not clear why you need to push it out so fast: data that is part of the UI really don't need to change more frequently that the UI is rendered (60 fps in JavaFX).

Comment: Maybe there is a set of data that are changing much more rapidly than the data displayed in the UI, but then that should probably be a different set of data. Maybe there needs to be some synchronization between two sets of data here? But it just looks like this is structured wrong. I would start by writing code that controls the hardware, and *then* write UI code that interacts with it. Those should basically be as independent and as decoupled as possible.

Comment: "Maybe there needs to be some synchronization between two sets of data here?" Yes, that is also my "latest" thought. And yes, the hardware needs the rapid updates, not the GUI, so you are right, they should be separate. What I initial wanted was to push the data fast to the hardware, and in the GUI show (when data was being changed) which data was being pushed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on above comments I have come up with this to fix the issue with multiple threads using the ObservableList. Below is based on the TimeLine for updating the ObservableList instead of the ScheduledExecutorService.

```
package org.example;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

    RadioButton radioButtonUseArray;
    RadioButton radioButtonUseObservableList;
    Timeline timeline1;
    Timeline timeline2;

    private final byte[] dmxDataArray = new byte[512];
    dmxDataObservable dmxDataArrayObservable = new dmxDataObservable(dmxDataArray);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        dmxDataArrayObservable.getBytes().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {

                System.out.println("Data updated");

            }

        });

        Button buttonStart = new Button("Start");
        buttonStart.setPrefWidth(100);
        buttonStart.setOnAction(event -> {

            StartTimeline1();
            StartTimeline2();

        });

        Button buttonStop = new Button("Stop");
        buttonStop.setPrefWidth(100);
        buttonStop.setOnAction(event -> {

            StopTimeline1();
            StopTimeLine2();

        });

        HBox hBoxWithStartStop1 = new HBox();
        hBoxWithStartStop1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBoxWithStartStop1.setSpacing(10);
        HBox.setHgrow(hBoxWithStartStop1, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hBoxWithStartStop1.getChildren().addAll(buttonStart, buttonStop);

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        radioButtonUseArray = new RadioButton("Use Array");
        radioButtonUseArray.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        radioButtonUseArray.setSelected(true);

        radioButtonUseObservableList = new RadioButton("Use Observablelist");
        radioButtonUseObservableList.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        HBox hBoxWithRadioButtons = new HBox();
        hBoxWithRadioButtons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBoxWithRadioButtons.setSpacing(10);
        HBox.setHgrow(hBoxWithRadioButtons, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hBoxWithRadioButtons.getChildren().addAll(radioButtonUseArray, radioButtonUseObservableList);

        VBox vBoxWithAllOptions = new VBox();
        vBoxWithAllOptions.setSpacing(10);
        vBoxWithAllOptions.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBoxWithAllOptions.getChildren().addAll(hBoxWithStartStop1, hBoxWithRadioButtons);

        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(vBoxWithAllOptions), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {

            StopTimeline1();
            StopTimeLine2();

        });

        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch();

    }

    public void StartTimeline1() {

        timeline1 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), e -> SendDataToDataContainers1()));
        timeline1.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE); // loop forever
        timeline1.play();

    }

    public void StopTimeline1() {

        if (timeline1 != null) {

            timeline1.stop();

        }

    }

    public void StartTimeline2() {

        timeline2 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), e -> SendDataToDataContainers2()));
        timeline2.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE); // loop forever
        timeline2.play();

    }

    public void StopTimeLine2() {

        if (timeline2 != null) {

            timeline2.stop();

        }

    }

    public void SendDataToDataContainers1() {

        if (radioButtonUseArray.isSelected()) {

            dmxDataArray[1] = (byte) 1;
            dmxDataArray[2] = (byte) 1;
            dmxDataArray[3] = (byte) 1;
            dmxDataArray[4] = (byte) 1;
            System.out.println("Running using array 1");

        } else if (radioButtonUseObservableList.isSelected()) {

            try {

                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(1, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(2, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(3, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(4, (byte) 1);
                System.out.println("Running using Observablelist 1");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

    public void SendDataToDataContainers2() {

        if (radioButtonUseArray.isSelected()) {

            try {

                dmxDataArray[1] = (byte) 1;
                dmxDataArray[2] = (byte) 1;
                dmxDataArray[3] = (byte) 1;
                dmxDataArray[4] = (byte) 1;
                System.out.println("Running using array 2");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        } else if (radioButtonUseObservableList.isSelected()) {

            try {

                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(1, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(2, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(3, (byte) 1);
                dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(4, (byte) 1);
                System.out.println("Running using Observablelist 2");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}
```